# Issues with selecting multiple files in Ubuntu 16 LTS

Tags: unity, nautilus, files, themes

Want to select multiple files with keyboard but can't see my current position (supposed to be dotted line or box) when navigating using the arrow keys. Could be a theme issue or bug. Using default theme (ambience). Any solution from experts?

Comment: What version of nautilus (`apt-cache policy nautilus`). I think this was a bug that was fixed. It works fine here in 16.04 using either shift+arrow keys for consecutive or ctrl+arrow keys  + space to select for non- consecutive.  In both cases position is seen by the  filename  highlighted with a dotted box

Comment: using nautilus version 3.14.3.

Comment: shift+arrow does work since its a solid colored selection. but ctrl+arrow dont show anything.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. So you don't get a dotted line box around the filename? (with either method) Here is short vid of using ctrl+arrow keys with space to select so we're 'on same page' so to speak. https://0x0.st/FmP.mp4 (can be watched in browser or dl'ed with r. click > save as

Comment: Correct. No dotted line in either of the method, although it is more of a problem in the non-consecutive (ctrl+arrow) case, i wouldnt mind if dotted lines dont show in shift+arrow case. Just discovered that if i change my theme to adwita then the dotted line shows. but in default theme the problem appears.

Comment: I use a nautilus build from my ppa, if inclined you could try it out. If using please read page  carefully 1st., xenial changes listed in bottom half. It is always updated with any security updates & includes some improvements from my perspective. https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/nauty-hacks1